# Python SQL multiple nullable parameters

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark-sql

Suppose we have a table `employees` which contains `name`, `employee_id` and `citizen_id`. We want to filter the table using also 3 python variables `name`, `employee_id` and `citizen_id` for the `WHERE` clause. Example:

```
name = 'John'
citizen_id = 'ID001'
employee_id = 'EMP023'
```

The condition is those 3 variables are `NULLABLE`, one or two of them can be `NULL` but at least one variable are not.
How we create a sql query that allow one/two of that 3 variables in the `WHERE` clause?

```
('''SELECT 
    *
FROM
    people
WHERE
    name = '{0}'
OR citizen_id = '{1}'
OR employee_id = '{2}'''').format(name, citizen_id, employee_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can distinguish the cases by adding

`.. AND <theRespectiveParameter> IS NOT NULL) OR <theRespectiveParameter> IS NULL` for each,

and change the currently stated operators between them from `OR` to `AND` considering parametrized query techniques for Spark SQL such as

```py
Q1 = spark.sql(('''
                  SELECT *
                    FROM people
                   WHERE ((name = {0} AND {0} IS NOT NULL) OR {0} IS NULL)
                     AND ((citizen_id = {1} AND {1} IS NOT NULL) OR {1} IS NULL)
                     AND ((employee_id = {2} AND {2} IS NOT NULL) OR {2} IS NULL)
                ''').format(name, citizen_id, employee_id)
```

**or** another option would be

```py
params  = {"name":name,               # based on current parameter names
           "citizen_id":citizen_id,
           "employee_id":employee_id}
           
Q1 = spark.sql(('''
                  SELECT *
                    FROM people
                   WHERE ((name = {name} AND {name} IS NOT NULL) OR {name} IS NULL)
                     AND ((citizen_id = {citizen_id} AND {citizen_id} IS NOT NULL) OR {citizen_id} IS NULL)
                     AND ((employee_id = {employee_id} AND {employee_id} IS NOT NULL) OR {employee_id} IS NULL)
                ''').format(**params)
```

getting rid of quotes for both cases

Comment: the `name`, `citizen_id`, `employee_id` after `OR` are the table column name?

Comment: Good catch @AMR , needed to replace them with parameter names. Btw, what's your DBMS?

Comment: not all DBMS able to do parameter on the left side of equation. I am using `SparkSQL` so it cannot be done through your solution.

Comment: @AMR Check out as a future reference please : [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)